# Does regex have the concepts "ultimate", "penultimate", and "antepenultimate" characters of a variable-length string?

Tags: regex

I feel seasick when watching video games, and regex causes in me the same sensation that other people get when they hear fingernails on a chalkboard, so I've avoided acquiring this skill; I'm the lesser programmer because of my weak constitution.

Can regex enforce this complex rule:

> in this variable length string, any character, no matter where it is, can be an "A", "B", or a "C"; but the final, penultimate, and antepenultimate characters can be a digit (0-9)

NOTE: the string might contain only 1 character, so "penultimate" and "antepenultimate" would not apply there; or it might contain 2 characters, in which chase "antepenultimate" would not apply.

Comment: Would `ABC1A1` be a legal string?

Comment: The actual rule is a little more complicated than the definition put forth in the question, where I was just trying to find out the basics. So, as the rule was defined above, yes, ABC1A1 would be legal. In actuality, however, the alpha chunk cannot be interrupted by a digit. It's actually an optional numeric `suffix`. And the string must contain at least one alpha to which the optional number can be attached. A1, A12, A999 are all good, but 1, 12, 999 alone are invalid. ABC, ABC100, ABC1, are all good; AB1C is bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is how you can do it:

```
^[ABC]*[ABC0-9]{1,3}$
```

If the rule is in fact that, if present, the digits must end the string contiguously, and that there needs to be at least one letter at the start, then you can use this regex:

```
^[ABC]+[0-9]{0,3}$
```

Comment: You can add explanation like this: From the start of the string (`^`), you can have as many "A", "B", or "C" as you want (even none) (`[ABC]*`), but the last 3 (if any, although at least one must present) (`{1,3}`) characters must end with "A", "B", "C", or digit (`[ABC0-9]`).

Comment: Because there might not be 3 characters at all, perhaps my edited comment is better understood. =)